# BFD unknown command when using gaddr2line

Tags: c, macos, backtrace, addr2line, bfd

I'm trying to use `gaddr2line` to print a prettier version of backtrace symbols.  I'm just getting the addresses from `backtrace()` then feeding them to `gaddr2line` by executing it using `popen`.  Using `addr2line` under linux works fine, but for some reason I'm getting strange errors when using `gaddr2line` on OS X.  When trying this on Mac OS I keep getting `BFD: ... : unknown load command ...`  I saw some posts metioning GDB, so I tried installing that with homebrew, but that didn't help.

Here is my code:

```
    // set to the maximum possible path size
    char exe_path[4096];

    // Used to check if an error occured while setting up command
    bool error = false;

    // Check if we are running on Mac OS or not, and select appropriate command
    char* command;
    #ifdef __APPLE__
        // Check if 'gaddr2line' function is available, if not exit
        if( !system( "which gaddr2line > /dev/null 2>&1" ) ) {
            command = "gaddr2line -Cfspe";
            pid_t pid = getpid();
            int path_length = proc_pidpath( pid, exe_path, sizeof( exe_path ) );
            if( path_length <= 0 ) {
                writeLog( SIMPLOG_LOGGER, "Unable to get execution path. Defaulting to standard backtrace." );
                error = true;
            }
            exe_path[path_length] = 0;
        } else {
            writeLog( SIMPLOG_LOGGER, "Function 'gaddr2line' unavailable. Defaulting to standard backtrace. Please install package 'binutils' for better stacktrace output." );
            error = true;
        }
    #endif
```

Here is the output:

```
gaddr2line -Cfspe /Users/nate/git/SimpleLogger/build/test 7408927
BFD: /Users/nate/git/SimpleLogger/build/test: unknown load command 0x2a
BFD: /Users/nate/git/SimpleLogger/build/test: unknown load command 0x28
BFD: /Users/nate/git/SimpleLogger/build/test: unknown load command 0x29
BFD: /Users/nate/git/SimpleLogger/build/test: unknown load command 0x2b
```